# Asp.Net Merge Columns and make a GridView Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I create a GridView with Datables and lists and i have a problem :
[GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klfA9.jpg)

My GridView have repetitive answers. 1 id_template has 1 name_template, but can have many id_forms (and many names : 1 id for 1 name).
i would like to merge it so as to have 1 id, 1 name, and their Ids and Names.
My code is like that :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id_Template");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name_Template");
        dt.Columns.Add("Id_Form_List");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name_Form_List");

        for (int i = 0; i < listeIdForm.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(listeIdTemplate[0], listeNomTemplate[0], listeIdForm[i], listeNomForm[i]);
        }
        GridView3.DataSource = dt;
        GridView3.DataBind();
```

Off Course, 1 Id is ont "Entity", so i would like to make a template, so as to have the same "table design" for each entity. Is it possible to make that without database datasource ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could zip all those lists(why you don't have a single classs with these properties?) and then use `GroupBy` to get the desired groups:

```
var tableSource = listeIdTemplate
    .Zip(listeNomTemplate, (id, nom) => new { id, nom })
    .Zip(listeIdForm, (x, idForm) => new { x, idForm })
    .Zip(listeNomForm, (x, nomForm) => new { x.x.id, x.x.nom, x.idForm, nomForm })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.id, x.nom });

foreach (var idNomGroup in tableSource)
    dt.Rows.Add(
        idNomGroup.Key.id,
        idNomGroup.Key.nom,
        string.Join(",", idNomGroup.Select(x => x.idForm)),
        string.Join(",", idNomGroup.Select(x => x.nomForm)));
```